# How to Use CASE, WHEN in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new to JPA and have the below JPA query:

```
String qry = " SELECT e from Event e"
                    + " WHERE e.meeting.meetingDate= :pdate"
                    + " AND e.meeting.feedId IN (1,2)"
                    + " AND e.status <> 'W'"
                    + " AND e.meeting.status ='A'"
                    + " AND e.settleStatus is NULL"
                    + " AND e.offTime is NULL"
                    + " AND e.eventCode >'07:45:00'"
                    + " group by e.id";
```

And I need to add the **ORDER BY** clause dynamically. I use MySQL and please anybody tell me how to add below condition to my query using **JPA**.

part to add:

```
ORDER BY
 CASE  WHEN m.country_code ='AU' THEN  e.timestamp_updated               
       WHEN m.country_code <> 'AU' THEN  e.event_code  
END DESC
```

how to add this query segment in to my JPA query?

Comment: create a procedure for it and then call this procedure by entityManager.createNativeQuery(storedProcedure);

Comment: could you please explain or help by an example?

Comment: its simple create a stored procedure and after that ping me,i will tell you the next step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JPA 2.0 you can use CASE WHEN in JPQL.

So you just have to do something like that:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN (e.property = ?) THEN 1
    WHEN (e.property = ?) THEN 2
    ELSE 3 
END DESC
```

You can also use Criteria API

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourEntity.class);
if(clause){
   criteria.addOrder( Order.asc("property_desired_1") );
}else{
  criteria.addOrder( Order.asc("property_desired_2") );
} 
criteria.list();
```

You can se more about criteria [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html#gjiwo), about JPQL CASE WHEN [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions) and about Order [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_orderby)

Comment: Although JPA 2.x supports `CASE` in JPQL it is not supported in `ORDER BY` clauses. This might go unnoticed, though, as Hibernate's implementation of JPQL, for instance, does support `CASE` in `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

This works protty god for me

My NATIVE Sql query

```
SELECT  
 another_column1, another_column2
CASE
    WHEN property_column = 'AU' then value_column ELSE 0
END AS LEARN,
CASE
    WHEN property_column = 'EU' then value_column ELSE 0
END AS Contribute 
FROM testing.mytablename;
```

JpaRepository / JPQL Query: returning a List < tuple >

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, UUID> {
    //c.columnNames are properties of MyTable class
    // take care of spaces and , caracters
    @Query("SELECT c.anotherColumn1, c.anotherColumn2, " +
            "  CASE c.propertyColumn WHEN 'AU' then c.valueColumn ELSE 0 END as learn," +
            "  CASE c.propertyColumn WHEN 'EU' then c.valueColumn ELSE 0 END as transfer " 
            "FROM MyTable AS c ") 
    List<Tuple> selectByPropertyCase();

}
```

FINALLY, if you want to MAP your query in a DTO Class

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, UUID> {
    //make sure to create the constructor for the dto classs
    @Query("SELECT SELECT new com.myprojectpath.model.MyTableClassDTO(c.anotherColumn1, c.anotherColumn2, " +
                "  CASE c.propertyColumn WHEN 'AU' then c.valueColumn ELSE 0 END as learn," +
                "  CASE c.propertyColumn WHEN 'EU' then c.valueColumn ELSE 0 END as transfer) " 
                "FROM MyTable AS c ") 
        List<MyTableClassDTO> selectByPropertyCase();
}
```